# mustache.js tr table rows every nth record?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, templates, mustache

I'm looking for a better solution than the code that I have using mustache.js
the template is creating tables of 2 rows and 2 columns, so I need to insert  at the start of each odd item, and  at the end of each even item.
I have no idea how to get mustache to do this, and I have resorted to inserting extra properties in the data to make this happen.

here is stackOverflows code editor attached to this question.
I'm using mustache version 1.00

e.g. my desired data is

```
[  [{name:"one"},{name:"two"},{name:"three"},{name:"four"}],
  [{name:"five"}] ];
```

but what I've resorted to using the following

```
[
  [{name:"one",rowstart: true},{name:"two",rowend: true},{name:"three",rowstart: true},{name:"four",rowend: true}],
  [{name:"five",rowstart: true}]
];
```

the resulting template I use is...

```
{{#.}}  
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm php">
    <table class="pagedTable">
    {{#.}}
      {{#rowstart}}
      <tr>
      {{/rowstart}}
       
        <td>{{name}}</td>
      
      {{#rowend}}
      </tr>
      {{/rowend}}
    {{/.}}

    </table>
  </section>
{{/.}}
```

my desired template would look something like the following...

```
{{#.}}  
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm php">
    <table class="pagedTable">
  {{#.}}
      {{#if index odd}}
      <tr>
      {{/if}}
       
        <td>{{name}}</td>
      
      {{#if index even}}
      </tr>
      {{/if}}
    {{/.}}

    </table>
  </section>
{{/.}}
```

I have to alter my data, which is problematic.

my question is can mustache insert  and  in the right spots at the right time? If so how do I do that?

## below is the SO code snippet

```js
var desiredData =  [
  [{name:"one"},{name:"two"},{name:"three"},{name:"four"}],
  [{name:"five"}] ];
var data = [
  [{name:"one",rowstart: true},{name:"two",rowend: true},{name:"three",rowstart: true},{name:"four",rowend: true}],
  [{name:"five",rowstart: true}]
];


var template = $('#template').html();

$('body.letter').append(Mustache.to_html(template,data));
```

```css
@page { margin: 0 }
body { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
}
.sheet {
  margin: 0mm auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  page-break-after: always;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

/** Paper sizes **/
body.A3           .sheet { width: 297mm; height: 419mm }
body.A3.landscape .sheet { width: 420mm; height: 296mm }
body.A4           .sheet { width: 210mm; height: 296mm }
body.A4.landscape .sheet { width: 297mm; height: 209mm }
body.A5           .sheet { width: 148mm; height: 209mm }
body.A5.landscape .sheet { width: 210mm; height: 147mm }
body.letter       .sheet { width: 216mm; height: 279mm }
body.letter.landscape       .sheet { width: 279mm; height: 216mm }

/** Padding area **/
.sheet.padding-10mm { padding: 10mm }
.sheet.padding-15mm { padding: 15mm }
.sheet.padding-20mm { padding: 20mm }
.sheet.padding-25mm { padding: 25mm }

/** For screen preview **/
@media screen {
  body { background: #e0e0e0;
    font-size: 13px; }
  .sheet {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
}

/** Fix for Chrome issue #273306 **/
@media print {
           body.A3.landscape { width: 420mm }
  body.A3, body.A4.landscape { width: 297mm }
  body.A4, body.A5.landscape { width: 210mm }
  body.A5                    { width: 148mm }
    body.letter.lanscape {width: 279mm }
}
.pagedTable {
    border-spacing: 4mm;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.pagedTable td {
    width: 90mm;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 123mm;
}
  
section.php {
    display: block;
}
section.js {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/1.0.0/mustache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body class="letter">
  
<script id="template" type="text/template">
{{#.}}  
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm php">
    <table class="pagedTable">
    {{#.}}
      {{#rowstart}}
      <tr>
      {{/rowstart}}
       
        <td>{{name}}</td>
      
      {{#rowend}}
      </tr>
      {{/rowend}}
    {{/.}}

    </table>
  </section>
{{/.}}
</script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that mustache is does not do if/else stuff, so I am sticking with what I have got, however I have copied and altered the desired data so that th e original array stays the same.

see below for updated SO code snippet also

```js
var desiredData =  [
  [{name:"one"},{name:"two"},{name:"three"},{name:"four"}],
  [{name:"five"}] ];

var altered = desiredData.map(element => element.map((x,i) => {
 if((i+1)%2 == 0){
   return Object.assign(x, {rowend: true})
 } else {
   return Object.assign(x, {rowstart: true})
 }
})) ;


var template = $('#template').html();

$('body.letter').append(Mustache.to_html(template,altered));
```

```css
@page { margin: 0 }
body { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
}
.sheet {
  margin: 0mm auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  page-break-after: always;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

/** Paper sizes **/
body.A3           .sheet { width: 297mm; height: 419mm }
body.A3.landscape .sheet { width: 420mm; height: 296mm }
body.A4           .sheet { width: 210mm; height: 296mm }
body.A4.landscape .sheet { width: 297mm; height: 209mm }
body.A5           .sheet { width: 148mm; height: 209mm }
body.A5.landscape .sheet { width: 210mm; height: 147mm }
body.letter       .sheet { width: 216mm; height: 279mm }
body.letter.landscape       .sheet { width: 279mm; height: 216mm }

/** Padding area **/
.sheet.padding-10mm { padding: 10mm }
.sheet.padding-15mm { padding: 15mm }
.sheet.padding-20mm { padding: 20mm }
.sheet.padding-25mm { padding: 25mm }

/** For screen preview **/
@media screen {
  body { background: #e0e0e0;
    font-size: 13px; }
  .sheet {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
}

/** Fix for Chrome issue #273306 **/
@media print {
           body.A3.landscape { width: 420mm }
  body.A3, body.A4.landscape { width: 297mm }
  body.A4, body.A5.landscape { width: 210mm }
  body.A5                    { width: 148mm }
    body.letter.lanscape {width: 279mm }
}
.pagedTable {
    border-spacing: 4mm;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.pagedTable td {
    width: 90mm;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 123mm;
}
  
section.php {
    display: block;
}
section.js {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/1.0.0/mustache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body class="letter">
  
<script id="template" type="text/template">
{{#.}}  
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm php">
    <table class="pagedTable">
    {{#.}}
      {{#rowstart}}
      <tr>
      {{/rowstart}}
       
        <td>{{name}}</td>
      
      {{#rowend}}
      </tr>
      {{/rowend}}
    {{/.}}

    </table>
  </section>
{{/.}}
</script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```